# hibernate transaction, commit not valid without active transaction

Tags: hibernate, transactional

first of all, sorry if my english is so bad, i am new in using hibernate so there is some question that i want to ask to all of senior.
here is the condition:
i am using zk for the view, in one view i have a toolbar that have (add),(save),(cancel) button. so what i want is when user klik (add) hibernate will start a new transaction and  then user insert some data after that user klik (save). in this (save) button event hibernate will call commit to insert the data to database.

the problem is when user klik save, it error with message
"commit not valid without active transaction"
after 1 trace the program flow i found that when user klik the (save) button, the transaction that i have started previously is not active anymore.

**## what i want to ask is why the transaction is inactive while i'm not commit it yet? ##**

i'am using spring with hibernate and 
hibernate.current_session_context_class = Thread

thank's for the help

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell without seeing the code. But what you want to do is a very bad idea. Don't do it. A transaction should be as short as possible. Letting a transaction open for a long time (your user could take a while between the *Add* and the *Save* clicks) leaves a connection open and not usable by other concurrent users, will probably lead to a timeout anyway, and could lock some database rows or tables, making all the other users wait for your transaction to finish.

The insertion in database and the commit should be done only when the user clicks the *Save* button. The modifications done by the *Add* button should not be persisted in database, but be stored in memory, until the user clicks *Save*.

Comment: yes, what you say is right but i have to do it this way because my application need transactional accross multiple event. hmmmmmm... but to save in memory is also a good idea too if i didn't need to lock the record.